# $ in page obstructing jquery calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a peculiar problem. Our js checks if jquery is available on a page and if not loads the js and we are using jquery to make a ajax call from that page

```
$.ajax({
url: url,...
```

But the problem is $ is already initialized within the page and now when our js is integrated, our calls doesnt work. We can't ask the page to make any change and we have to live with that restriction and have a workaround.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

You can enclose your script in a `document.ready` handler *and* pass in jQuery as a parameter at the same time.

Try this...

```
jQuery(function($) {

    // put all your script inside here

})(jQuery);
```

That means you can use `$` in your script that's enclosed with that wrapper, and it won't be affected by any other libraries that declare it elsewhere.

If your script was previously in a `document.ready` handler then just remove it as that does the job for you.

Comment: Thats not a `document.ready` - its just a self-executing function.

Comment: @Jamiec `jQuery(function() { ... })` is a document ready handler (or `$(function() { ... })`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery` as a replacement for `$`.

```
jQuery.ajax({
url: url,...
```

Comment: How $ of the page and $ of jquery dont override or vice-versa